# Using levels in MapIndexed

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

I am trying to use `MapIndexed` to manipulate a matrix of data but I am having trouble getting the levels parameter to work the way I would like. Suppose that my data looks like this, with every odd column being a count and the even columns being some piece of data:

```
a = {{11, d11, 21, d21, 31, d31}, 
    {12, d12, 22, d22, 32, d32}, 
    {13, d13, 23, d23, 33, d33}, 
    {14, d14, 24, d24, 34, d34}};

b = {{11, d11, 0, Null, 31, d31}, 
    {12, d12, 0, Null, 32, d32}, 
    {13, d13, 0, Null, 33, d33}, 
    {14, d14, 0, Null, 34, d34}};

c = {{0, Null, 0, Null, 31, d31}, 
    {0, Null, 0, Null, 32, d32}, 
    {0, Null, 0, Null, 0, Null}, 
    {0, Null, 0, Null, 34, d34}};
```

As you can see, some odd columns will have a zero count and the corresponding data column will be `NULL`. Edit: *I have changed `c` to reflect some new bits of information about the data. There may be some rows that contain the `0, NULL` pattern, but I only want to eliminate columns in which the first row is like this. The first row is a sum of the following rows, and I only want to eliminate a column if it has no data at all. This is why I structured the `For` loop in the way I did. Based on the responses, I felt I needed to clarify.* I'd like to eliminate both the count and data columns any time this is the case. For example, after some operation I'd like to have:

```
a0 = {{11, d11, 21, d21, 31, d31}, 
     {12, d12, 22, d22, 32, d32}, 
     {13, d13, 23, d23, 33, d33}, 
     {14, d14, 24, d24, 34, d34}};

b0 = {{11, d11, 31, d31}, 
     {12, d12, 32, d32}, 
     {13, d13, 33, d33}, 
     {14, d14, 34, d34}};

c0 = {{31, d31}, 
     {32, d32}, 
     {0, NULL}, 
     {34, d34}};
```

I accomplished this using a hack with a `For` loop but this is obviously not the proper way to use Mathematica and I was directed to `MapIndexed`:

```
a0 = For[i = 1, i < Length @ a[[1]], i = i + 2, 
         If[a[[1, i]] == 0,
             a = Drop[a, None, {i, i + 1}];
             i = i - 2
         ]
     ];
```

How can I get `a0` with something of this form?:

```
a0 = MapIndexed[f, a, list];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Transpose[c] //. {before___, {0..}, {Null..}, after___} :> {before, after} // Transpose
```

> ```
> {
>  {31,  d31}, 
>  {32,  d32}, 
>  { 0, Null}, 
>  {34,  d34}
> }
> ```

**Update:**

In case of column headers as in the comment below, the patterns in the rule need to modified slightly:

```
Transpose[c] //. {before___, {_, 0..}, {_, Null..}, after___} :> {before, after} // Transpose
```

> ```
> {
>  {"h3", "d3"}, 
>  {  31,  d31}, 
>  {  32,  d32}, 
>  {   0, Null}, 
>  {  34,  d34}
> }
> ```

Comment: This line works correctly for the given data, but it does not work if there are column headers like `head = {"h1", "d1", "h2", "d2", "h3", "d3"}` that I would like to keep. Is there a simple way to work around this to produce `f[PrependTo[c, head]] = {{"h3","d3"},{31, d31},{32, d32},{0,  Null},{34, d34}}`

Comment: The update works beautifully on my data set, thank you.

Comment: Suppose that instead of only wanting to eliminate columns whose first (non-header) entry is 0, I also would like to eliminate columns whose first (non-header) entry is below a certain threshold - say 1% of the first value in the farthest right column. Can this be done using a similar `RuleDelayed`?

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Why don't you post this as a new question with one or two examples?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way typical for *Mathematica*:

```
c //. {a___, _, Null, b___} :> {a, b}
```

Comment: Could you explain what that command does? I'm a new user.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try to replace the documentation because I would not be as eloquent. `//.` is short for `ReplaceRepeated` and it will apply the replacement rule to the right until several times until nothing changes (which is necessary if several columns have to be removed). `:>` is short for `RuleDelayed`, the distinction between `RuleDelayed` and `Rule` is the same as that between `Set` and `SetDelayed`. The patterns: `___` matches any sequence of elements, even an empty one. `_` matches a single arbitrary element. Reading about these things in the docs is the best way to learn.

Comment: Thank you. Even though this is a good answer, I'd still like to see it done with `MapIndexed` so I can see an example with that function.

Comment: Given OP's example, why not `c /. 0 | Null -> Sequence[]`?

Comment: @Nick It appears eldo has tried that now. As you can see it's more complicated.

Comment: @rm-rf The way I interpreted the OP was that the the corresponding data column to a zero could be NULL, not that it had to be.

Comment: To me the cleanest way to do this is the way rm-rf first presented it (and eldo's first example). To be clear I want to eliminate the columns entirely and the columns following 0 entries are always NULL

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the data. I have a hunch these solutions with `Sequence[]` may not work in this case.

Comment: @Nick I don't think any of the old solution will work in this case. I won't update this answer, but Teake Nutma's answer is in the same spirit as what I wrote but works for your data.

Answer (score 3):

```
c /. (0 | Null) -> Sequence[] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
DeleteCases[MapIndexed[pos, c, {2}, Heads -> False], pos[0 | Null, _], 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Given that the OP asked for an explanation of my rule, I think you should at least outline what you're doing in your second piece of (non-trivial) code.

Comment: @eldo It is not clear to me that this provides the desired answer to the OP's question. In particular, for the c matrix, the third row is transformed to {} rather than the desired {0, Null}.

Comment: @ecoxlinux The question was changed / appended 2 hours after my answer. I think that Pickett's solution handles this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that seems fast (and only checks the first row, as the OP suggested in the question):

```
c[[
  All, 
  Flatten@Select[
    Partition[Range@Length@First@c, 2] , 
    c[[1, #]] != {0, Null} &]
]]
```